# Upload XML file, put in temporary folder or localStorage and access contents

Tags: php, jquery, xml, file-upload

I have an HTML form as such which consists of a input type=file.

```
<form method="post" id="xml-upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" accept=".xml" required name="xml-selection-hidden" id="upload-btn">
</form>
```

(There is no submit button, submit is triggered via jQuery:)

```
$("input[type=file]#upload-btn").change(function(){
    $("form#xml-upload").submit();
});
```

That's the easy part. Now, I am not quite knowledgeable in PHP file handling so the next part is harder for me. My idea of how these things work is that I make a PHP file and link to it in the action attribute of the form. For instance `action="upload.php"`.

First of I need to check the file type, XML only (might allow TXT in the feature, but not of yet). A maximum size of the file of around 200kB ought to suffice. Simply using an embedded if-clause seems fine? (not tested)

```
if(($_FILES["file"]["type"]=="text/xml")) {
 if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000) {
 // run function
 } else {
 // error: max file size is 200kB
 }
} else {
// error: only xml files are allowed
}
```

But now I'm stuck.

The goal is to manipulate the XML client-side. This is useful because I allow users to either choose the file upload option, or to give a direct XML input in a textarea. The server-side function (jQuery) for parsing the XML in the textarea is already finished, so it would be useful if I could use the same function to parse the XML that I get from the uploaded file.

I thought of two options:

**`1.`** The uploaded file is put in a temporary directory *with a random name*, I then run an ajax call with jQuery to the file. But how? How do I get jQuery to know where the file is stored?

**`2.`** Store the content of the uploaded file in localStorage and manipulate it accordingly. When a new file is uploaded, the older localStorage ought to be cleared of course.

The script that is run on the XML is something along these lines. Just so you know what happens with the XML input:

```
var xml = $("textarea#xml-input").val(),
    xmlParsed = $.parseXML(xml),
    xmlObject = $(xmlParsed);

$("#tree").html(output(xmlObject.find('node').first()));

function output(nodes) {
    var newList = $("<ol>");
    nodes.each(function (x, e) {
        var newLI = $('<li><a href="">&nbsp;</a></li>');
        for (var i = 0, l = e.attributes.length, a = null; i < l; i++) {
            a = e.attributes[i];
            newLI.attr("data-" + a.nodeName, a.value);
            if (a.nodeName == "cat") {
                newLI.html('<a href="#">' + a.value + '</a>');
            }
            else if (a.nodeName == "word") { 
                newLI.html('<a href="#">' + a.value + '</a>');
            }
        }
        if ($(this).children('node').length) {
            newLI.append(output($(this).children('node')));
        }
        newList.append(newLI);
    });
    return newList;
}
```

As I have said, I have tried my best in this post and gave it all I got, but I lack the knowledge. Looking for some help here. All help welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For doing same as you wants you can create your own "xml_tmp" folder in your server root and then by using PHP move_uploaded_file() function to store your file in directory you selected for this and after storing current uploaded xml file you can ask via AJAX to get file name and path then send the requested info back to the client by using jQuery.parseXML() method you can read and manipulate your xml there.

I hope it help you!

**Storing uploaded file by PHP:**

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "xml_tmp/tmp.xml")
```

Imagine that 'xmlSrc' variable is the result of response from you AJAX call for requesting xml path and name

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: xmlSrc,
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml,
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $author = $xml.find( "author" );

    // append the text from your parsed xml element to some HTML element
    $( "#element" ).append( $author.text() );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> **1.** The uploaded file is put in a temporary directory with a random name, I then run an ajax call with jQuery to the file. But how? How do I get jQuery to know where the file is stored?

jQuery has no interest in the temporary filename. The moment your [PHP script has processed the upload request](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php), the temporary file is deleted. That's on the server-side. jQuery is on client side.

So jQuery would get a filename of an inexistent file then.

You're perhaps looking for [the browser file API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File) which is able to access contents of a file *without* uploading it. Which seems fair as you're anyway dealing with a textbox if I understood your question right.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly the browser file API would not require a form to be submitted. Merely a file selection through the input type. (But how does that work. Is the file copied to a tmp dir on the user's device?) This way seems perfect for my case, indeed. Could you elaborate on the usage? Do consider that the file ought to be parsed as XML in a jQuery function.

Comment: please move the mouse cursor over that part in my answer. it should turn into a pointing finger. you then can click it and your browser will take you to the documentation. an it's javascript not jQuery btw. and all javascripts have [DOMDocument for XML parsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

Comment: I did. And I read the documentation. But a more elaborate explanation and relevant example that is applicable to my use case would be nice.

Comment: @BramVanroy: Sure, just place four brand new Sportcars in front of my home and put the keys into my letterbox. I'll let you know which one I give back to you and which three I'll take till the end of the week.

Comment: Well, excuse me for asking for an *actual* answer. Your "answer" is much more suitable as a comment, as it doesn't answer anything. It gives keys where to look - which is fine and helpful, but as a comment. **Not** as an answer.

Comment: Well, if I see that right I at least spared you the roundtrip through the server. For as broad as your question is, I'd say that is at least something to keep for later. And an answer doesn't have to be posting code (and for your use-case I'm pretty sure Q&A material on the site already exists so perhaps don't direct the request directly to me, but also to the community as a whole and in past time especially and search around a little)